# Arrow between two baselines

Tags: pdftex, arrows

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\def\texttext{This is a sample text}
\newlength{\textlength}
\settowidth{\textlength}{\texttext}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\rule{5pt}{.1pt}\rule{\textlength}{.1pt}\kern-\textlength \texttext\rule{5pt}{.1pt}

\rule{5pt}{.1pt}\rule{\textlength}{.1pt}\kern-\textlength \texttext\rule{5pt}{.1pt}

\end{document}
```

I want to draw an two-headed arrow between the baselines. Doubtless this is possible with TikZ, but can it also be done in plain Latex.

Comment: At which point? Beginning of lines? End?

Comment: Of course it can, after all Ti*k*Z is implemented in TeX. Why do you want to do that though?

Comment: @bernard At the end.

Comment: @Skillmon. Just for fun.

Comment: @Skillmon - Most of what TikZ does goes straight to the PDF driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution (with trial and errors):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, old-arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\texttext{This is a sample text}
\newlength{\textlength}
\settowidth{\textlength}{\texttext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xleftrightarrow[2][]{%
 \ext@arrow 9999{\longleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\longleftrightarrowfill@{%
 \arrowfill@\leftarrow\relbar\rightarrow}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\rule{5pt}{.1pt}\rule{\textlength}{.1pt}\kern-\textlength \texttext\rule{5pt}{.1pt}\raisebox{-0.62ex}[0pt][0pt]{ \rotatebox[origin=l]{-90}{$ \xleftrightarrow{\makebox[1.44ex]{}} $}}

\rule{5pt}{.1pt}\rule{\textlength}{.1pt}\kern-\textlength \texttext\rule{5pt}{.1pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I take it `\resizebox` would be cheating?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\def\texttext{This is a sample text}
\newlength{\textlength}
\settowidth{\textlength}{\texttext}

\newcommand{\clap}[1]{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \hspace{-0.5\wd0}\usebox0\hspace{-0.5\wd0}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\rule{5pt}{.1pt}\rule{\textlength}{.1pt}\kern-\textlength \texttext\rule{5pt}{.1pt}

\rule{5pt}{.1pt}\rule{\textlength}{.1pt}\kern-\textlength \texttext\rule{5pt}{.1pt}%
  \clap{\raisebox{\depth}[0pt]{\large$\updownarrow$}}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Would it be cheating?

Comment: Like TikZ, graphics goes straight to the PDF driver.  Except for pict2e (which uses specialized fonts) TeX has no graphics capability.